# Create an arraylist in mule and iterate over it

Tags: list, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I want to create an arrayList and iterate over its entries to check if my message has the set properties

```
        <set-variable variableName="ex" value="#[{'A', 'User-Agent', 'Application-ID', 'API-Key', 'P', 'Organization-ID'}]" doc:name="Set Variable" />
        <for-each collection="#[ex]" doc:name="Foreach">
           <choice doc:name="Choice">
             <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.contains([payload]) == false]">
                <set-variable variableName="isRequestValid" value="false" doc:name="Variable"/>
             </when>
           </choice>
        </for-each>
```

I am getting an error at the for-each expression (Invalid content was found starting with element 'for-each'). Further can we use choice block without otherwise option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It should be `foreach`
2. List can be initialised as `#[['A','B']]`
3. If you don't need otherwise i.e. just filter out payload, you can use `expression-filter` inside foreach -

```html
    <set-variable variableName="ex" value="#[['A', 'User-Agent', 'Application-ID', 'API-Key', 'P', 'Organization-ID']]" doc:name="Set Variable" />
    <foreach collection="#[ex]" doc:name="Foreach">
        <expression-filter expression="#[message.inboundProperties.contains([payload]) == false]" doc:name="Expression"/>
        <set-variable variableName="isRequestValid" value="false" doc:name="Variable"/>
    </foreach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an old Mule version, for-each construct was included in 3.4 (see [release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-esb-3.4.0-release-notes)), I cannot think of an other reason for that error.
Unfortunately you cannot use choice without otherwise, but there is an improvement reported: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6129

Answer (score 0):

It shall be `foreach` instead of `for-each`.

We can use Choice block without *otherwise* option. But it will introduce runtime error when the value does not match with the logic in *when* option.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it to foreach construct, but how would I check if my request contains header defined in the list? I am getting error Execution of the expression "message.inboundProperties.contains([payload]) == false" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String

Comment: To access the original *message* from `foreach` scope, use *rootMessage* (this is the default value). Double click `foreach` scope and see the value of *Root Message Variable Name*. It also listed as variable, you can find it in Mule Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already resolved the issue with for-each, remaining issue can be resolved using following expression

```
#[message.inboundProperties[payload] !=null]
```

If it returns `true` then header present otherwise not.

Hope this helps.